# Get rows which do have references to list of values and at the same time don't have any references to list of other values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sure it was asked before but I just can't figure out how to search for it

I have a table table1:

```
| RefId_1 | RefId_2 |
---------------------
|       1 |     133 |
|       3 |      12 |
|       4 |     144 |
|       4 |      22 |
|       3 |     123 |
```

I need to get list of `RefId_1` which do have reference to list of `RefId_2` but don't have any references to another list of `RefId_2`.

For example, I need list of `RefId_1` which references to `RefId_2` list of (133, 22, 44) but such `RefId_1` should not have references to list of `RefId_2` (12, 144, 111).

Result should be just (1) because (4) references to forbidden 144

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you meant 22,144 not 22,111 in the last line ;-)

Comment: I am sorry, the task is more complicated than just not in (), I'll edit it

Comment: In your given `133, 22, 44` where `44` in table?

Comment: Can you give your expected output in table format. This question is confusing me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** : (**UNTESTED**)

```
SELECT DISTINCT REF_ID1 FROM table1 
    WHERE REF_ID2 IN(133,22,44)
    AND
    REF_ID1 NOT IN 
              (SELECT REF_ID1 FROM table1 WHERE REF_ID2 IN (12, 144, 111))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT RefId_1
FROM yourtablename
WHERE 
  RefId_2 IN (133, 22, 44)
  AND RefId_2 NOT IN (12, 144, 111);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this It must work which you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT REF_ID1
FROM table1
WHERE REF_ID1 NOT IN
    (SELECT REF_ID1
     FROM table1
     WHERE REF_ID2 IN (12,144));
```